# dipsaying a poitive and negative on clickable text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the code below which allows me ad show data based on a user clicking on of the title but i am trying to add a positive image next to it which is easily done, but when the user click on the heading and the data is displayed would like to show negative.png and when they click to hide the data again i would like to show positive.png

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div >
        <div class="layer1">
            <p class="heading">To view report fields click here</p>
                <div class="content" >
                     <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h4>Gender</h4></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h4>Percentage</h4></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>   
                </div> 
         </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.layer1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}

.heading {
margin: 1px;
color:Black;
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
.content {
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color:#fafafa;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(".content").hide();
     //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
     jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
         jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(400);
     });
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toggleClass`. Write different class to toggle

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(".content").hide();
     //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
     jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
         jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(400);
         jQuery(this).toggleClass("collapse");
     });
 })
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N6MCd/1/)**

More explanation about **[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

Comment: i dont undertsnad what you mean

Comment: dont understand?? :O are you familiar with jQuery??

Comment: I am new to jquery a colloegue did this and told me to add positive or negative imahe

Comment: toggleClass is an event which toggles the class name. When you click on the p tag it adds the class called "collapse" to p tag, which allows to add - symbol. Read this document http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: i create a css class called collapse and onclick it adds this class and once clicked again is goes back to the origanl state